# D3 Zooming on X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

I’m trying to add a zoom feature to my bar chart. What I’m trying to achieve is when a user drags his cursor over a certain area, you should be able to zoom in to that area and the x axis value change to showing the number of days in that month. 
Following [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/godds/ec089a2cf3e06a2cd5fc) I’ve tried to incorporate the same zoom and drag feature.

But I seem to be getting this error:

```
Error: <rect> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,0)".
```

What I’m trying to do with the zoom feature is once zoomed in the x axis should change from showing months (Jan, Feb, etc) to days (1 Jan, 2 Jan, 3 Jan, etc).
Any help would be apperiated.
Here’s the code for the zoom feature:

```
function bListener() {         
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x.domain() : brush.extent());

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log(d.date); return "translate(" + x(d.date) + ",0)"; });

    svg.select(".x axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

[Here’s the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/dty0s24k/34/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` function expects to be passed a number so d3 can work with it.
Currently youre passing it a string. `d.date` in this case is a the string `"2013-03-21"`.
You need to format this into a number so that `x` can return a number for the `translate` function.
In this case change it into a `date object` using `x(new Date(d.date))`

```
svg.selectAll(".bar").attr("transform", function(d) { 
    console.log(d.date); 
    return "translate(" + x(new Date(d.date)) + ",0)"; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've changed the data object but my x axis don't seem to update. Any idea on how to fix this? http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/dty0s24k/35/

Comment: your xAxis function plots ticks using months - `.orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.month)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b %y'))`.  Simply calling this, like you are, wont change the ticks, because youre not changing anything. You should check out some tutorials on d3 - start and build a graph up rather than jumping in and the end product. Itll make a difference in the long run.

Comment: I looked at the where i was creating the xAxis and noticed the plotting and format. Was going to come back on here to post it but you beat me to it. As far as "jumping in and the end product". I did create the chart using tutorials. I would admit i'm not very knowledgeable about D3.

Comment: @user3837019 my bad on the presumption. Yeah theres a lot to d3.

Comment: that's ok. I'm grateful for the help and answer.